# On some subgroups of $S_{p^{n}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

For a prime number $p$, a natural number $n \geq 1$ and a set $X$ with $p^n$ elements, let us define here an "interesting" subgroup of $S_X$ as an abelian subgroup $P$ of order $p^n$ of $S_X$ such that every element of $P \setminus \{1 \}$ is the product of $p^{n-1}$ pairwise disjoint $p$-cycles. Clearly, such a subgroup is the direct product of $n$ groups of order $p$. Clearly also, the "interesting" subgroups of $S_X$ are in bijection with the "interesting" subgroups of $S_{p^n}$.

Here is a proof that "interesting" subgroups always exist :

Statement 1. Let $p$ be a prime number and $n \geq 1$ a natural number. Let $X$ denote the direct product of $n$ groups of order $p$, noted additively. Then the translations in $X$ :

$T_a : x \mapsto x + a$

form an "interesting" subgroup of $S_X$. (The proof is easy.) Clearly, this can be transported from $X$ to every set $Y$ with $p^n$ elements.

My question is : let $p$ be a prime number and $n \geq 1$ a natural number; is it necessarily true that all "interesting subgroups" of $S_{p^n}$ are conjugate in $S_{p^n}$ ?

If $n = 1$, it is true, since every "interesting" subgroup of $S_{p^1}$ is generated by a $p$-cycle.

Here is a proof that it is also true if $n = 2$. Let $P$ be an "intersting" subgroup of $S_{p^2}$. Then $P$ is the direct product of $2$ subgroups of order $p$. Choose two elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $P \setminus \{1 \}$ such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ generate $P$. Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not powers of each other, and from this, it is easy to conclude that the support of a cycle in the canonical decomposition of $\alpha$ and the support of a cycle in the canonical decomposition of $\beta$ never have two common elements. (Keep in mind that no element of $P \setminus \{1 \}$ has a fixed point.) Thus there is an enumeration $x_1, ... , x_{p^2}$ of $1, ... , p^2$ such that

$\alpha = (x_{1}, ... , x_{p}) (x_{p +1}, ... , x_{2p}) ... (x_{p^2 - p +1}, ... , x_{p^2}) $

and that the canonical decomposition of $\beta$ in cycles has the cycle $(x_{1}, x_{p +1},  x_{2p +1}... , x_{p^{2} - p+1})$. Expressing that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ commute, we find that

$\beta = (x_{1}, x_{p +1},  x_{2p +1}... , x_{p^{2} - p+1})  (x_{2}, x_{p +2},  x_{2p +2}... , x_{p^{2} - p+2})... (x_{p}, x_{2p}, ... , x_{p^2}) $.

Since $P$ is generated by $\alpha$ and $\beta$, it results that all "interesting" subgroups of $S_{p^2}$ are conjugate in $S_{p^2}$.

I presume that for every $n \geq 1$, all "interesting" subgroups of $S_{p^n}$ are conjugate in $S_{p^n}$, but, at first glance, I don't see a way to prove it at once.

I don't necessarily ask for a proof. If you can give a reference to the literature, it is already good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are the generators of your group, then using their action we give "coordinates" to the set $J=\{1,2,\ldots,p^n\}$ in such a way that we pick the origin $(0,0,\ldots,0)\in\Bbb{F}_p^n$ arbitrarily, and then define the coordinates to the other points by declaring that action by $\alpha_k$ increments the $k$th coordinate. Using the resulting collection of coordinates gotten from any two interesting groups should give a straightforward proof of your claim for all $n$.

Comment: (cont'd) Matching the coordinates gives a bijection between two copies of $J$, and thus give the needed conjugation. More precisely, if $\alpha_1',\ldots,\alpha_n'$ generate some other interesting group, then with $\gamma$ defined by $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)\mapsto (a_1',a_2',\ldots,a_n')$ we get $\gamma\alpha_j\gamma^{-1}=\alpha_j'$ for all $j$.

Comment: I'm looking for a suitable old thread using this idea, but no luck so far. Hope you can use my coarse hint. It is actually very similar to your proof for the case $n=2$.

Comment: This is just Cayley's Theorem applied to elementary abelian groups, together with the elementary result that all regular permutation representations of a group are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @Derek Holt . I need to revise representations of groups on sets...